# Flatten json string array into pandas dataframe in Python

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have a JSON string which has call data, and each call contains several kvp data points. Inside the KVPdata array, there will be list of key value pairs for each kvptype. The goal here is to flatten this JSON into several records and output as pandas dataframe. I need some inputs on how to convert this string into the below tabular format using pandas dataframe.

input =

```
[
  {
    'callId': 'ff0818c8',
    'kvpdata': [
      {
        'kvptype': 'customer',
        'kvpdict': {
          'attribute1': 'value1',
          'attribute2': 'value2',
          'attribute3': 'value3',
          'attribute4': 'value4'
        },
        'agentId': '9f1989ab-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4',
        'commIds': [
          '3af52ec2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68'
        ]
      },
      {
        'kvptype': 'queue',
        'kvpdict': {
          'attribute1': '10',
          'attribute3': '[value3]'
        },
        'agentId': '36285ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766',
        'commIds': [
          '95e8cca0-401a-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3'
        ]
      }
    ],
    '_type': 'calldata'
  },
  {
    'callId': 'sfsdfsd23',
    'kvpdata': [
      {
        'kvptype': 'customer',
        'kvpdict': {
          'attribute1': 'v1',
          'attribute4': 'value4'
        },
        'agentId': '92323b-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4',
        'commIds': [
          '3adsds2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68'
        ]
      },
      {
        'kvptype': 'queue',
        'kvpdict': {
          'attribute1': '10',
          'attribute3': '[value3]',
          'attribute8': 'value8'
        },
        'agentId': '3dd5ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766',
        'commIds': [
          '95e8cca0-dfda-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3'
        ]
      },
      {
        'kvptype': 'agent',
        'kvpdict': {
          'attribute9': '80',
          'attribute6': '23'},
        'agentId': '56d5ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766',
        'commIds': [
          '00e8cca0-dfda-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3'
        ]
      }
    ],
    '_type': 'calldata'
  }
]
```

I am looking for the below output as pandas dataframe:

[image]

I tried the json_normalize function, but I didn't get the right results.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option is to use [`json_normalize`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html)/[`melt`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.melt.html) :

```
out = (pd.json_normalize(obj, "kvpdata", [["callId"]], errors="ignore")
           .melt(["callId", "kvptype", "agentId", "commIds"],
                 value_name="kvpdict_attribute_Value", ignore_index=False)
           .assign(kvpdict_attribute= lambda x: x.pop("variable").str.split(".").str[1])
           .dropna(subset="kvpdict_attribute_Value").sort_index()
       [["callId", "kvptype", "kvpdict_attribute",
         "kvpdict_attribute_Value", "agentId", "commIds"]]
      )
```

​
Output :

```
​
print(out)

      callId   kvptype kvpdict_attribute kvpdict_attribute_Value                               agentId                                 commIds
0   ff0818c8  customer        attribute1                  value1  9f1989ab-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4  [3af52ec2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68]
0   ff0818c8  customer        attribute2                  value2  9f1989ab-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4  [3af52ec2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68]
0   ff0818c8  customer        attribute3                  value3  9f1989ab-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4  [3af52ec2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68]
0   ff0818c8  customer        attribute4                  value4  9f1989ab-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4  [3af52ec2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68]
1   ff0818c8     queue        attribute1                      10  36285ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766  [95e8cca0-401a-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3]
1   ff0818c8     queue        attribute3                [value3]  36285ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766  [95e8cca0-401a-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3]
2  sfsdfsd23  customer        attribute1                      v1    92323b-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4   [3adsds2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68]
2  sfsdfsd23  customer        attribute4                  value4    92323b-d1b6-4498-8cf7-f195918f92b4   [3adsds2-53b0-4c4b-a833-6d09e9058d68]
3  sfsdfsd23     queue        attribute1                      10   3dd5ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766  [95e8cca0-dfda-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3]
3  sfsdfsd23     queue        attribute3                [value3]   3dd5ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766  [95e8cca0-dfda-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3]
3  sfsdfsd23     queue        attribute8                  value8   3dd5ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766  [95e8cca0-dfda-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3]
4  sfsdfsd23     agent        attribute9                      80   56d5ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766  [00e8cca0-dfda-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3]
4  sfsdfsd23     agent        attribute6                      23   56d5ba0-a87e-4b29-afe8-4aa29189b766  [00e8cca0-dfda-4b3e-9f1e-60f5934880f3]
```

Comment: Honestly, likely a great answer...but without looking at source I cannot tell why this works. Why not be more concise?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. What sources are you talking about ?

Comment: The code for pandas. Normally I'd think you state why a method in whichever library you use works for the OPs issue for completeness (i.e json_normalize/melt)...adding the base solution (at least for learners) does not aid in problem solving (per a quick overview), it just provides a solution

Comment: Well, my sources are pandas docs : https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/index.html